# jQuery too much recursion yii cgridview

Tags: php, jquery, yii, jquery-events, cgridview

I have 2 CGridView calling each other on `beforeAjaxUpdate`. How can I prevent the recursion? I only want it to call the other one once?

**jobs-grid**

```
'beforeAjaxUpdate' =>'function(id,options){     
    var x = getQueryParams(options.url);
    var data = "sort="+x.Jobs_sort + "&ajax=detailsgeoscan-grid";
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update("detailsgeoscan-grid",{data:"sort="+x.Jobs_sort});
}',
```

**detailsgeoscan-grid**

```
'beforeAjaxUpdate' =>'function(id,options){
    var x = getQueryParams(options.url);
    var data = "Jobs_sort="+x.Jobs_sort + "&ajax=jobs-grid";
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update("jobs-grid",{data:"sort="+x.Jobs_sort});
}',
```

Comment: Did you try my answer. A feedback would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with an optional parameter `isNotFirst`:

**jobs-grid**

```
'beforeAjaxUpdate' =>'function(id,options,isNotFirst){     
    var x = getQueryParams(options.url);
    var data = "sort="+x.Jobs_sort + "&ajax=detailsgeoscan-grid";
    if(typeof isNotFirst === "undefined"){
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("detailsgeoscan-grid",{data:"sort="+x.Jobs_sort}, true);
    }
}'
```

**detailsgeoscan-grid**

```
'beforeAjaxUpdate' =>'function(id,options,isNotFirst){
    var x = getQueryParams(options.url);
    var data = "Jobs_sort="+x.Jobs_sort + "&ajax=jobs-grid";
    if(typeof isNotFirst === "undefined"){
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("jobs-grid",{data:"sort="+x.Jobs_sort},true);
    }
}',
```

If `isNotFirst` is `undefined`, the function is called by yii, so you can call the function of the other grid with `isNotFirst` set to true.